# Resize IPython.display.Audio bar

Tags: python, audio, widget, ipython, jupyter

Is there a way to resize the audio display bar in jupyter notebooks? For example, if I wanted the bar to be twice the width of its default. This would help scrubbing given a longer audio duration.

```py
from IPython import display
audio_path = "./data/audio.wav"
display.Audio(filename=audio_path)
```

[image]

We want to extend the size of the grey display to be the length of the red line drawn. Is this possible with IPython.display.Audio, or is there an alternative library that can do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I read the documentation, and it seems width is not an argument to adjust width in the Audio function, unless I am missing something. I'm trying to figure out if there is a general way to resize Ipynb.display objects that can be applied, but am not having much luck...

Comment: Is my question unclear, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
audio_style = "<style>audio { margin-left: 35px; width: 1260px; }</style>"
display(HTML(audio_style))
```

Comment: It works for me. I just put @19greg96's snippet right before the following codes: `import IPython
IPython.display.Audio(wav)`